# Security of Docker as it runs as root user

Tags: security, docker

A Docker [blog post](http://blog.docker.io/2013/08/containers-docker-how-secure-are-they/) indicates:

> Docker containers are, by default, quite secure; especially if you
>   take care of running your processes inside the containers as
>   non-privileged users (i.e. non root)."

So, what is the security issue if I'm running as a root under the docker? I mean, it is quite secure if I take care of my processes as non-privileged users, so, how can I be harmful to host in a container as a root user? I'm just asking it to understand it, how can it be isolated if it is not secure when running as root? Which system calls can expose the host system then?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you run as root, you can access a broader range of kernel services. For instance, you can:

- manipulate network interfaces, routing tables, netfilter rules;
- create raw sockets (and generally speaking, "exotic" sockets, exercising code that has received less scrutiny than good old TCP and UDP);
- mount/unmount/remount filesystems;
- change file ownership, permissions, extended attributes, overriding regular permissions (i.e. using slightly different code paths);
- etc.

(It's interesting to note that all those examples are protected by [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).)

The key point is that as root, you can exercise more kernel code; if there is a vulnerability in that code, you can trigger it as root, but not as a regular user.

Additionally, if someone finds a way to break out of a container, if you break out as root, you can do much more damage than as a regular user, obviously.

Comment: So you would be almost safe when the docker you run runs a non-root user to execute arbitrary stuff

Comment: I would like to have root access in the container, but make sure it couldn't break out the host system. This is makes it easier to do the single app single container philosophy.

Comment: The last sentence regarding breaking out of a container is a little misleading.  If you can break out of a container, regardless of who you were inside the container, you would break out as who the LXC process itself is running as on the host OS.  This is often root.  That said, it's still a good idea to run container processes as a non-privileged user, since that makes it harder to break out of the container (at least in theory).

Comment: I feel like people don't think about what you can do inside the container if you're root. I exploited your app, maybe I can't jailbreak, but everything in that container are belong to me. How long will it take before you notice someone has updated your running container? especially because you probably don't have something like tripwire installed in it because it's a container...

Answer (score 7):

You can reboot host machine by echoing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` on docker. Processes running as root in docker can do this.

This seems quite good reason not to run processes as root in docker ;)

Comment: I get `bash: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Read-only file system`

Comment: Well... after two years they finally fixed something?