# What security concerns exist when running Docker?

Tags: security, host, docker

I can't find any documentation regarding security concerns for Docker. I understand how to create a *relatively* secure host machine by locking down the firewall, ssh access, user accounts and passwords, and turning off unnecessary services.

Are these same concerns applicable in a Docker environment? Or is a Docker environment isolated and initially locked down so that there are no "holes" unless explicitly opened/allowed, thereby making the only security concerns necessary being the security concerns on the host??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security of Docker as it runs as root user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054029/security-of-docker-as-it-runs-as-root-user)

Comment: @AlisterBulman my question is similar, however I'm asking about security concerns in a broader sense. However, the blog post linked in that question *does* answer my concerns.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor if you could please post that link as an answer, I would be able to accept it. Also, as I found in the blog post:

"The information in this blog post (and many other useful security details) will soon be integrated in the Docker main documentation as well."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker blog contains a security related posting:

- http://blog.docker.io/2013/08/containers-docker-how-secure-are-they/

**EDIT**: The newest and most updated document answering the question is here with almost similar content as the original blog : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/